# What is the correct REST URL in Drupal 8 (or 9)?

Tags: api, drupal-8, rest

I know there's been a lot of work to deprecate the `extern` endpoints in CiviCRM, and the `extern` endpoints don't work in Drupal 8 without a lot of finagling.  The documentation isn't updated to reflect a new way of using D8 REST endpoints, nor is API Explorer.  Does anyone know what the "correct" endpoint is?

Comment: I think this is still in flux so need to add the word "today" on the end of the question (grin). See also https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2077 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17952

Answer (score 3):

My previous answer here is now out dated.  Now the endpoint is `/civicrm/ajax/rest`.  But first you must enable the AuthX extension (**Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**).  Then you'll have an Authentication menu at **Administer menu » System Settings » Authentication**.  There is a link to documentation from there that provides instructions for more complex workflows.

Comment: I used a symbolic link to ```<drupal root>/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/extern``` in ```<drupal root>/web/libraries/civicrm/core``` since that will, I hope, make sure that the folder remains in date. 

i

Answer (score 3):

I just installed a CiviCRM and Drupal 9 instance (5.40.1). These were my steps:

- I enabled the new authx extension `cv ext:enable authx`
- I allowed the authenticate with the api_key in a special header `cv ev 'Civi::settings()->set("authx_xheader_cred",["api_key"]);'` The auth extension does not have a configuration screen, yet.
- I added site key as an extra protection `cv ev 'Civi::settings()->set("authx_guards",["site_key"]);'`.
- I flushed the CiviCRM cache `cv flush`

And now the following CURL command can be used to call the REST api:

```
curl -X GET --location "http://<<server>>/civicrm/ajax/rest? 
entity=Contact&action=get&json=1" \
-H "X-Civi-Auth: Bearer <<api_key>>" \
-H "X-Civi-Key: <<site_key>>" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
```