# Drupal 9/CiviCRM REST api issue

Tags: rest

Is anyone using the REST API with Drupal?  Nothing I have tried from the docs seems to work.

I am trying to connect with CallHub and they require the REST endpoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have documented a working example at [What is the correct REST URL in Drupal 8 (or 9)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37926/what-is-the-correct-rest-url-in-drupal-8-or-9). It needs however some magic with HTML headers, I wonder if that's an option with CallHub.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not working but there is some work being done on it here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19727